# h : $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $h(x) = (f(x),g(x))$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $U \subset \mathbb R^n$. Let $f, g : U \to \mathbb R$ two  differentiable functions $\forall x \in U$. I want to show that the function h : $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $h(x) = (f(x),g(x))$.

The definition of differentiability I am using is the following :

$f : E \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable in $x_0 \in \mathring{E}$ if $f$ can be written as
$$f(x) = f(x_0) + D_f(x_0)(x-x_0) + g(x) \text{ with } \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\lVert g(x) \rVert}{\lVert x-x_0 \rVert}=0$$

I really struggle with ugly formulas to prove that $h$ can be written like this using the fact that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable $\forall x \in U$.

Comment: There is no need for ugly formulas. Try to write $h$ in the desired form using $D_f(x_0)$ and $D_g(x_0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta_f>0$ such that such that$$\|x-x_0\|<\delta_f\implies\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-D_f(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|}<\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt2}\tag1$$and take $\delta_g>0$ such that such that$$\|x-x_0\|<\delta_g\implies\frac{|g(x)-g(x_0)-D_g(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|}<\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt2}.\tag2$$Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$ and define$$\begin{array}{rccc}L\colon&\Bbb R^n&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&x&\mapsto&\bigl(D_f(x_0)(x),D_g(x_0)(x)\bigr).\end{array}$$Then $L$ is linear and, if $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$, $\displaystyle\frac{\|h(x)-h(x_0)-L(x-x_0)\|}{\|x-x_0\|}$ is equal to$$\frac{\bigl\|\bigl(f(x)-f(x_0)-D_f(x_0)(x-x_0),\bigl(g(x)-g(x_0)-D_g(x_0)(x-x_0)\bigr)\bigr\|}{\|x-x_0\|},$$which is equal to$$\left\|\left(\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-D_f(x_0)(x-x_0)}{\|x-x_0\|},\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)-D_g(x_0)(x-x_0)}{\|x-x_0\|}\right)\right\|.\tag3$$But, due to $(1)$ and to $(2)$, and since $\|(a,b)\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $(3)$ is smaller than $\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon^2}2+\frac{\varepsilon^2}2}=\varepsilon$. This shows that $h$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and that $D_h(x_0)=L$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider so called Jacobi matrix$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_2} \\
\dfrac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_2} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
And you can see that your function $h(x)$ at point $x_0 = (a, b)$ can be written as
$$ h(x)  = (f(x), h(x))^T = (f(x_0), h(x_0))^T + J(x_0)((x_1, x_2)^T - (a,b)^T) +o(|(x_1, x_2)^T - (a,b)^T|) $$